# Building error on changegeometryvalues

Tags: qgis, features, c++, api

I am working with c++/QT and c++api gqis 2.8.2

I want to change the geometry of a feature,
I have this code :

```
QgsVectorLayer * lLayer = mMapLayer.value(TRACKS);
QgsVectorDataProvider * lDataProvider;
lDataProvider = lLayer->dataProvider();
//create point
gsGeometry * MyPoint;
MyPoint = QgsGeometry::fromPoint(QgsPoint(PosX,PosY));
QgsGeometryMap MyGeometryMap;
QgsFeatureId MyFeatureId;

MyGeometryMap.insert(MyFeatureId,MyPoint);

lDataProvider->changeGeometryValues(MyGeometryMap);
```

I don't understand why i have an error on the insert :

error: no matching function for call to
 ‘QMap::insert(QgsFeatureId&, QgsGeometry*&)’
  MyGeometryMap.insert(MyFeatureId,MyPoint);
                                          ^
src/IHM/mainwindow.cpp:599:42: note: candidate is:
In file included from /usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.8.5/include/QtCore/qvariant.h:49:0,
                 from /usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.8.5/include/QtCore/QVariant:1,
                 from /usr/local/include/qgis/qgis.h:25,
                 from src/Core/common.h:13,
                 from src/Core/libcarto.h:12,
                 from src/IHM/mainwindow.h:24,
                 from src/IHM/mainwindow.cpp:20:

Any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution

```
gsGeometry * MyPoint;
MyPoint = QgsGeometry::fromPoint(QgsPoint(PosX,PosY));
QgsGeometryMap MyGeometryMap;
QgsFeatureId MyFeatureId;

MyGeometryMap.insert(MyFeatureId,*MyPoint);
```

or  this way

```
gsGeometry MyPoint;
MyPoint.fromPoint(QgsPoint(PosX,PosY));
QgsGeometryMap MyGeometryMap;
QgsFeatureId MyFeatureId;

MyGeometryMap.insert(MyFeatureId,MyPoint);
```

sorry for this stupid error.